# Jquery Easy UI multiselect entered characters are not clearing after selection

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-easyui

I am using Jquery easyUI library for multi-select text box with autocomplete.
When I enter some text its showing drop down items matching that character.

**But the issue is after selecting that drop down item it is appending to entered character separated by comma.**

In this example I entered "**J**" and selected "**java**" from dropdown list but that selected item is appended to entered text.
[image]

How I can remove that entered text once item is selected from the dropdown.

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.jeasyui.com/easyui/jquery.easyui.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Multiple Select - jQuery EasyUI Demo</title>

</head>

<body>
   <h2>Load Dynamic ComboBox Data</h2>
    <p>Drop down the panel and select multiple items.</p>
    <div style="margin:20px 0"></div>
    <div class="easyui-panel" style="width:100%;max-width:400px;padding:30px 60px;">
        <div style="margin-bottom:20px">
            <input class="easyui-combobox" name="language[]" style="width:100%;" data-options="
                    url:'https://api.myjson.com/bins/pj2h3',
                    method:'get',
                    valueField:'id',
                    textField:'text',
                    multiple:true,
                    panelHeight:'auto',
                    label: 'Language:',
                    labelPosition: 'top'
                    ">
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: It looks like it's `multiple:true` that does the problem

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen Its multiselect box. It should take take multiple values. So multiple:true.